# Without quotations, OnClick function is calling automatically

Tags: javascript, onclick

The script I wrote has a button that, when clicked, should show year and IP address, but it does automatically. I saw in another 3D that this issue comes when in the "onclick" option you put a function like

```
<button name="bottone" onclick=myFunction()>AH-AH</button>
```

but this is not my case.

```
<button name="bottone" onclick=myFunction>AH-AH</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(json) {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();
    var ip = json.ip;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n + ' ' + ip;
}
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=myFunction"></script>
```

Seems like the second script "overrides" the option onClick.

Comment: Not really clear what's happening, the button doesn't work or the function gets called even if you don't click?

Comment: Hi uraimo, sorry for my bad explaination and poor language property. The function gets called even if I dont click.

Comment: Ok, check my answer then, that script on jsonip.appspot.com is calling your function explicitly, when you finish loading that script, it calls your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script calls your function immediately:

```
myFunction({"ip": "88.9.35.40", "address":"88.9.35.40"});
```

Instead, you could store the data in a variable, and use that variable in the event handler:

```html
<button name="bottone">Display year and IP</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
(function() {
  var ipData;
  window.getIpData = function(data) { // We must use awful global for JSONP
    delete window.getIpData; // Get rid of the awful global
    ipData = data;
  };
  document.getElementsByName('bottone')[0].onclick = function() {
    if(ipData) {
      var year = new Date().getFullYear(),
          ip = ipData.ip;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = year + ' ' + ip;
    }
  }
})();
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getIpData"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Oriol, thanks for your reply. The code works!
I have to ask you a couple of questions:
1st: why you put all the script's content in a parenthesis? I mean (...code...)();
2nd: window is an object like document, that can be invoked without any constructor? And you created the field window.getIpData making an assignment?
3rd: ipData is a particular type, or as above, you defined his field ip?

I hope i haven't been blasphemous and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: @user4804285 Maybe my [first edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29716665/revisions#revb2d0555e-de8b-48f5-af2f-b228e3a9adfd) was a bit simpler. I use a self executing function (`(function(){ /*code*/ })()` to prevent `ipData` from being global. `window` is the global object. Since the 3rd-party script can only call global functions, I define `getIpData` in `window`, and I delete it once it has been used (I hate global variables). `ipData` is a variable which can have a value of any type (objects, numbers, strings, ...), in this case it will be undefined initially, and then an object.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explaination!

Answer (score 2):

1. Change that onClick to `onclick="myFunction()"`, that's how it should be (always use the quotes, it's a function call so include the parenthesis).
2. That second script invokes directly the function you are passing as callback parameter `?callback=myFunction`, so it will call *autonomously* your `myFunction()`.

Try opening [that script url](https://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=myFunction) directly in your browser to see what the script will execute:

```
myFunction({"ip": "11.11.11.81", "address":"11.11.11.81"});
```

Comment: Hi again, I put quotes and parenthesis on onClick but nothing seems to work. I opened the script on my browser and had a reply like yours. So?
Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: Quotes and parenthesis are just the right formatting, where not meant to fix anything. Your function gets called because calling your function is the only thing that script does, if you don't need it you should remove it.

Comment: If you are italian, Quello script da jsonip.appspot.com semplicemente ricava l'ip del client, scrive una riga di javascript che invoca la tua funzione  e la invoca, non fa altro. Quello che vedi aprendo nel browser è il codice che verrà eseguito.

Comment: Ciao uraimo, era così palese che fossi italiano? Maledetti verbi e periodi complessi... :D 
Grazie per la spiegazione!

Comment: E' quel *bottone* che ti ha tradito, eheheh

Comment: Giusto! Dai, meglio così allora :D
Comunque non mi è completamente chiaro ancora perchè la risposta veniva data in automatico :/

Comment: Quello script che includi, genera codice javascript aggiungendo l'ip corrente come parametro della tua funzione (conosce il nome della funzione perchè è un parametro dell'url, quel `?callback=nomefunzione`) e il browser lo esegue, lo esegue subito, è come se tu avessi incluso un file javascript esterno che conteneva una sola riga `myFunction();`, il browser scarica il js e poi esegue myFunction(); funziona così l'inclusione dei file javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code. The script u included, was calling a callback fucntion, and inside that it was printing Date and Ip onload of page.
So I have kept that showing ip and date code in separate function.

The variable which are used for display of date and Ip> I made them global, so those variable can be used outside callback method.

```html
<button name="bottone" onclick="showIpNDate()">AH-AH</button>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
        var ip, n;
    
        function myFunction(json) {
            var d = new Date();
            n = d.getFullYear();
            ip = json.ip;
    
        }
    
        function showIpNDate() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n + ' ' + ip;
        }
    </script>
    
    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=myFunction"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Ankuli, thanks for your reply. The code still doesn't work, but I discovered there's the chance to put "global" variables in a script and multiple functions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user4804285 U sure. its not working.
But i can't see any errors while running the above code.